# Template for loop replacement

Tags: c++, templates, recursion

I'm working on something that loops over a potentially multi-dimensional array and I am running into some template issues. Here is the idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
template<std::size_t D = 3>
class Deriv {
public:
    typedef typename boost::array<double, D> results_t;

    template<typename Iterator>
    results_t operator()(Iterator& objIterator)
    {
        double u;
        double um1;

        results_t derivs;

        for(results_t::index i = 0; i < D; ++i) {
           u = *objIterator;
           um1 = *(objIterator.left<i>(1));
           derivs[i] = u-um1;
        }
     }
   };
};
```

So, it looks a little confusing, but it's using a custom iterator that has a `left` and `right` template method where the template parameter is the dimension to move left or right in and the argument is the offset. For example, if `objIterator` points to `array[i][j][k]`, then `objIterator.left<0>(1)` returns an iterator to `array[i-1][j][k]`.

Obviously what I posted doesn't work because `i` is not compile time and can't be used as the parameter for `left`. I feel like recursion could be used here somehow to make this happen by replacing that for loop, but I don't know how.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach:

```
template<std::size_t D = 3>
struct Deriv
{
    typedef typename boost::array<double, D> results_t;

private:
    template<std::size_t I>
    struct apply
    {
        template<typename Iterator>
        static void impl(results_t& derivs, Iterator& iter)
        {
            derivs[I] = *iter - *iter.template left<I>(1);
            apply<I + 1>::impl(derivs, iter);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct apply<D>
    {
        template<typename Iterator>
        static void impl(results_t&, Iterator&) { }
    };

public:
    template<typename Iterator>
    results_t operator ()(Iterator& iter) const
    {
        results_t derivs;
        apply<0>::impl(derivs, iter);
        return derivs;
    }
};
```

I've tested with VC++ 2010, but I suspect it may not compile on more conformant compilers. If you can count down from `D-1` through `0` rather than up from `0` through `D-1`, then the following should be okay:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<std::size_t I>
    struct apply
    {
        template<typename ResultsT, typename Iterator>
        static void impl(ResultsT& derivs, Iterator& iter)
        {
            derivs[I] = *iter - *iter.template left<I>(1);
            apply<I - 1>::impl(derivs, iter);
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct apply<0>
    {
        template<typename ResultsT, typename Iterator>
        static void impl(ResultsT& derivs, Iterator& iter)
        {
            derivs[0] = *iter - *iter.template left<0>(1);
        }
    };
}

template<std::size_t D = 3>
struct Deriv
{
    typedef typename boost::array<double, D> results_t;

public:
    template<typename Iterator>
    results_t operator ()(Iterator& iter) const
    {
        results_t derivs;
        detail::apply<D - 1>::impl(derivs, iter);
        return derivs;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a C++ compiler handy, but that should solve your problem:

```
template<typename Iterator, int dimNo>
void processDim(results_t & derivs, Iterator& objIterator) {
    if(dimNo==-1) return;
    double u;
    double um1;
    u = *objIterator;
    um1 = *(objIterator.left<dimNo>(1));
    derivs[dimNo] = u-um1;

    processDim<Iterator,dimNo!=D?dimNo+1:-1>(derivs, objIterator);
}

template<typename Iterator>
results_t operator()(Iterator& objIterator)
{

    results_t derivs;
    processDim<Iterator, 0> (derivs,objIterator);
    return derivs;
}
```

You have a hidden smiley in the code too!

BTW, if you're able to modify the `Iterator` type that's coming, you could make it receive the dimension as a regular argument (not a template parameter) if the only reason it's a template parameter is for performance in the first place. I'm sure the compiler will figure out that it could simply unfold the loop. This way, you don't need any ugly recursive templates.

Answer (score 0):

General idea, mod it as you see fit.

```
// recursive
template<typename Iterator, int I>
void apply(Iterator& objIterator, results_t &derivs, mpl::int_<I>) {
       u = *objIterator;
       um1 = *(objIterator.left<I>(1));
       derivs[I] = u-um1;
       apply(objIterator, derivs, mpl::int_<I-1>());
 }
// terminate
template<typename Iterator>
void apply(Iterator& objIterator, results_t &derivs, mpl::int_<-1>) {}
```

also look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/for-each.html

Comment: @ildjarn it looks like it but it's not.  this is:  `template<typename T>void apply<T>(`

Comment: Yeah, I realized that shortly after submitting the comment and deleted it. :-]